# Small Office Server Provisioning Recommendations (Hyper-V or Metal)

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I'll be setting up a new network for my small software dev team, and I have a question about how to best set up the servers.

The requirements are:

- Active Directory (and DNS) for local network
- File Services for local network
- DHCP for local network
- Routing and Remote Access for local network access remotely
- Exchange Server 2016 for business email
- Hyper-V VMs for some Linux web servers (development and testing environments only)

Would it be best to set up a Hyper-V host, and then provision a VM to run AD + DNS + DHCP + RRAS + File Services, another VM to run Exchange, and then any other Linux VMs required?

Or, would it be best to provision a separate physical machine to take care of AD + DNS + DHCP + RRAS + File Services, and have only Exchange and the Linux machines running under Hyper-V?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide details below?

1) Small software dev team is how small? 10, 20, 40, 80? staff?

2) How many clients will be connected to active directory?

Are you going to set up the server OS's mentioned in one Rack/Tower server? What is the configuration of  CPU, RAM and disk storage for the server?

My suggestions and feedback to share below.

1) Installing either VMware ESXi or Windows server with Hyper-V role installed on the physical server. Let VMware ESXi or Hyper-V manage all the remaining CPU, memory and disk space for the virtual machines.

2) If installing Windows server on the physical server these two points need to be considered.

- Not to install any type of server configuration other than Hyper-V. To prevent any complications affecting the other virtual servers. i.e. if Active Directory was installed and configured to on physical server if it needed a restart it'll effect virtual machines running on it.
- Running any other roles other than Hyper-V role on Windows Server could lead decreased efficiency of CPU, memory and disk space utilised by other virtual machines.

3) As each server will be a virtual machine an advantage is one or more backup server can be created and powered off so as to not utilising any CPU and memory usage. Then be powered on when the primary server fails; if enough CPU and memory reserve are available or it'll slow down all virtual machines. Thus allowing two domain controllers one primary and one only as a backup.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Currently a team of 6 with 10 Active Directory clients. I'm intending on utilizing a tower server with 2 Intel Xeon X5650 processors,  32GB of RAM and ~2TB of SAS disks in RAID5. Thanks for the suggestions and feedback.